# Unit test with Swift: body of closure not executed

Tags: swift, unit-testing, closures

There are functions that send a request to server, get response and print result.  They always work in the iOS app itself but only sometimes (looks like randomly) in unit-tests of this app.

Main issue: Xcode doesn't enter the body of a closure in unit-tests, just skips it.

Any ideas how can it be fixed? [Image of the problem in Xcode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFGeF.jpg)

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most likely reason because the completion closure of your requests are not being exectued is that they are performing an **asynchronous** operation, while the tests run synchronously. This means that the test finishes running while your network request is still processing.

Try using [`XCTestExpectation`](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/):

```
func testIt() {
  let expectation = expectationWithDescription("foobar")

  // request setup code here...

  Alamofire.request(.POST, "...")
    .responseJSON { response in
      //
      // Insert the test assertions here, for example:
      //
      if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        XCTAssertEqual(JSON["id"], "1")
      } else {
        XCTFail("Unexpected response")
      }

      //
      // Remember to call this at the end of the closure
      //
      expectation.fulfill()
  }

  //
  // This will make XCTest wait for up to 10 seconds,
  // giving your request expectation time to fulfill
  //
  waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10) { error 
    if let error = error {
      XCTFail("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```